# Problema con el POST de fetch en una API de flask

Tags: post, flask, fetch, requests

Estoy haciendo una API con flask que calcula las alturas de un lugar a partir de un DEM local. La API ya calcula los valores, he probado el funcionamiento de la API con insomnia haciendo POST de dos coordenadas de la linea del perfil y obteniendo las elevaciones a lo largo de esa linea. Sin embargo cuando hacemos la petición POST con fetch la API no nos retorna los datos que solicitamos, aunque la consola del servidor nos muestra los datos.

POST con fetch:

````
```
const url = 'http://localhost:4000/products'

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "Punto_inicial": [-74.092389, 4.636756 ],
    "Punto_final":[-74.078618, 4.645129]
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())```
````

En la API creamos la función para hacer el POST con lo siguiente:

```
@app.route('/products',methods=['POST'])
def addProduct():

    profile = Perfil(request.json["Punto_inicial"],request.json["Punto_final"])
    profile.datos_perfil()
    return jsonify(profile.profile_json)
```

Finalmente el perfil es creado de la siguiente manera:

```
import argparse
import sys
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import json

class Perfil():

    def __init__(self,Punto_inicial,Punto_final):
        self.Punto_inicial = Punto_inicial
        self.lat_1 = self.Punto_inicial[1]
        self.lon_1 = self.Punto_inicial[0]

        self.Punto_final = Punto_final
        self.lat_2 = self.Punto_final[1]
        self.lon_2 = self.Punto_final[0]
        

    def datos_perfil(self):
        
        dist = 1
        src= "DEM_05_wgs.tif"
        tif = ""

        ds = gdal.Open(src)

        if not ds:
            print("Could not open dataset.")
            sys.exit(1)
        
        # Set up coordinate transform
        proj_str = "+proj=tpeqd +lon_1={} +lat_1={} +lon_2={} +lat_2={}".format(self.lon_1, self.lat_1, self.lon_2, self.lat_2)
        tpeqd = CRS.from_proj4(proj_str)
        transformer = Transformer.from_crs(CRS.from_proj4("+proj=latlon"), tpeqd)

        # Transfor to tpeqd coordinates
        point_1 = transformer.transform(self.lon_1, self.lat_1)
        point_2 = transformer.transform(self.lon_2, self.lat_2)
        
        # Create an bounding box (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) in tpeqd coordinates
        width = 1
        bbox = (point_1[0], -(width*0.5), point_2[0], (width*0.5))

        # Calculate the number of samples in our profile.
        num_samples = int((point_2[0] - point_1[0]) / dist)
        
        # Warp it into dataset in tpeqd projection. If args.tif is empty GDAL will
        # interpret it as an in-memory dataset.
        format = 'GTiff' if tif else 'VRT'
        profile = gdal.Warp("l.tif", ds, dstSRS=proj_str, outputBounds=bbox, 
                            height=1, width=num_samples, resampleAlg="near", 
                            format=format)

        # Extract the pixel values and write to an output file
        data = profile.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
        
        print("Created {}m profile with {} samples.".format(dist*num_samples, num_samples))

        elevation = data[0]
        distance = np.arange(len(elevation)) * dist
        
        profile_points = {
            'distancia_x': list(distance.astype('float')),
            'elevacion': list(elevation.astype('float'))
        } 

        self.profile_json = profile_points
        
        with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.profile_json, f, ensure_ascii=False)


        self.profile_json
```